# Cracking cryptographic function with radare2

Tags: assembly, radare2, arm

I want to reverse engineer an android game, found a method

```
public static byte[] MNNOPKMJMFP(byte[] AFFEPNLBIIC, byte[] OENOGNMAMPO, byte[] GLLEHJKGIBK) { }
```

Names are obfuscated, i know that this is a cryptographic function that takes three arguments - an array of bytes, key and initialization vector, i want to get their specific values, for example, an 256 bit AES key, these are dynamic objects so they have a pointer and they are in heap, this is the code from radare2 disassembler

```
fcn.00c63d2c ();
│           ; var int32_t var_24h @ fp-0x24
│           0x00c63d2c      f04f2de9       push {r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, sb, sl, fp, lr}
│           0x00c63d30      1cb08de2       add fp, sp, 0x1c
│           0x00c63d34      0cd04de2       sub sp, sp, 0xc
│           0x00c63d38      0080a0e1       mov r8, r0
│           0x00c63d3c      d0029fe5       ldr r0, [0x00c64014]        ; [0xc64014:4]=0x18f53fc
│           0x00c63d40      0260a0e1       mov r6, r2
│           0x00c63d44      0170a0e1       mov r7, r1
│           0x00c63d48      00008fe0       add r0, pc, r0
│           0x00c63d4c      0000d0e5       ldrb r0, [r0]
│           0x00c63d50      000050e3       cmp r0, 0
│       ┌─< 0x00c63d54      0600001a       bne 0xc63d74
│       │   0x00c63d58      b8029fe5       ldr r0, [0x00c64018]        ; [0xc64018:4]=0x1884b04
│       │   0x00c63d5c      00009fe7       ldr r0, [0x00c63d64]        ; [0xc63d64:4]=0xebdc4331
│       │   0x00c63d60      000090e5       ldr r0, [r0]
│       │   ; DATA XREF from fcn.00c63d2c @ 0xc63d5c(r)
│       │   0x00c63d64      3143dceb       bl 0x374a30
│       │   0x00c63d68      ac029fe5       ldr r0, [0x00c6401c]        ; [0xc6401c:4]=0x18f53d4
│       │   0x00c63d6c      0110a0e3       mov r1, 1
│       │   0x00c63d70      0010cfe7       strb r1, [0x00c63d78]
│       └─> 0x00c63d74      a4029fe5       ldr r0, [0x00c64020]        ; [0xc64020:4]=0x186d7dc
│           0x00c63d78      08504de2       sub r5, sp, 8
│           0x00c63d7c      00009fe7       ldr r0, [0x00c63d84]        ; [0xc63d84:4]=0xe5900000
│           0x00c63d80      05d0a0e1       mov sp, r5
│           ; DATA XREF from fcn.00c63d2c @ 0xc63d7c(r)
│           0x00c63d84      000090e5       ldr r0, [r0]
│           0x00c63d88      bf10d0e5       ldrb r1, [r0, 0xbf]
│           0x00c63d8c      020011e3       tst r1, 2
│       ┌─< 0x00c63d90      0300000a       beq 0xc63da4
│       │   0x00c63d94      701090e5       ldr r1, [r0, 0x70]
│       │   0x00c63d98      000051e3       cmp r1, 0
│      ┌──< 0x00c63d9c      0000001a       bne 0xc63da4
│      ││   0x00c63da0      197fdceb       bl 0x383a0c
│      └└─> 0x00c63da4      0000a0e3       mov r0, 0
│           0x00c63da8      baa1eceb       bl 0x78c498
│           0x00c63dac      0040a0e1       mov r4, r0
│           0x00c63db0      000054e3       cmp r4, 0
│           0x00c63db4      24500be5       str r5, [var_24h]           ; 0x24
│       ┌─< 0x00c63db8      0100001a       bne 0xc63dc4
│       │   0x00c63dbc      0000a0e3       mov r0, 0
│       │   0x00c63dc0      7cfddceb       bl 0x3a33b8
│       └─> 0x00c63dc4      000094e5       ldr r0, [r4]
│           0x00c63dc8      283190e5       ldr r3, [r0, 0x128]
│           0x00c63dcc      2c2190e5       ldr r2, [r0, 0x12c]
│           0x00c63dd0      0400a0e1       mov r0, r4
│           0x00c63dd4      0710a0e1       mov r1, r7
│           0x00c63dd8      33ff2fe1       blx r3
│           0x00c63ddc      000094e5       ldr r0, [r4]
│           0x00c63de0      183190e5       ldr r3, [r0, 0x118]
│           0x00c63de4      1c2190e5       ldr r2, [r0, 0x11c]
│           0x00c63de8      0400a0e1       mov r0, r4
│           0x00c63dec      0610a0e1       mov r1, r6
│           0x00c63df0      33ff2fe1       blx r3
│           0x00c63df4      000094e5       ldr r0, [r4]
│           0x00c63df8      241190e5       ldr r1, [r0, 0x124]
│           0x00c63dfc      202190e5       ldr r2, [r0, 0x120]
│           0x00c63e00      0400a0e1       mov r0, r4
│           0x00c63e04      32ff2fe1       blx r2
│           0x00c63e08      0060a0e1       mov r6, r0
│           0x00c63e0c      000094e5       ldr r0, [r4]
│           0x00c63e10      102190e5       ldr r2, [r0, 0x110]
│           0x00c63e14      141190e5       ldr r1, [r0, 0x114]
│           0x00c63e18      0400a0e1       mov r0, r4
│           0x00c63e1c      32ff2fe1       blx r2
│           0x00c63e20      0020a0e1       mov r2, r0
│           0x00c63e24      000094e5       ldr r0, [r4]
│           0x00c63e28      887190e5       ldr r7, [r0, 0x188]
```

- what did i understand from this?

- r0: used to work with pointers,
- r1, r2, r3 - used to pass arguments and temporary values,
- r4-r8 - used as temporary registers and, possibly, for storing pointers,
- sb, sl, fp - used to save stack frame's state and set it,
  Addresses used as pointers `[0x00c64014], [0x00c64018], [0x00c6401c], [0x00c64020]` are loaded into register r0 and used to access data in memory
  `[r0]` is a pointer that the function operates in several places,
  Also, will i be able to find the answer to my question in addresses offset from [r0] or not? for example `[r0, 0xbf], [r0, 0x70], [r0, 0x128], [r0, 0x12c], [r0, 0x118], [r0, 0x11c], [r0, 0x124], [r0, 0x120], [r0, 0x110], [r0, 0x114], [r0, 0x188]`, Also this is the method (pattern for building other functions), will xrefs analysis help?
  Will be thankful for any tip!

Answer (score 0):

I am strongly recommend to you use Ghidra. It can provide much more clear 'C-like' output. For example, for your function, it gives

```
void FUN_00000000(undefined4 param_1,undefined4 param_2,undefined4 param_3)
{
  int *piVar1;
  undefined auStack_38 [12];
  undefined *local_2c;
  
  if (PTR_000002e8[0x24] == '\0') {
    func_0xff710d04(**(undefined4 **)(PTR_000002ec + 0x38));
    PTR_000002f0[0x4c] = 1;
  }
  if (((*(byte *)(**(int **)(PTR_000002f4 + 0x58) + 0xbf) & 2) != 0) &&
     (*(int *)(**(int **)(PTR_000002f4 + 0x58) + 0x70) == 0)) {
    func_0xff71fce0();
  }
  piVar1 = (int *)func_0xffb2876c(0);
  local_2c = auStack_38;
  if (piVar1 == NULL) {
    func_0xff73f68c(0);
  }
  (**(code **)(*piVar1 + 0x128))(piVar1,param_2,*(undefined4 *)(*piVar1 + 300));
  (**(code **)(*piVar1 + 0x118))(piVar1,param_3,*(undefined4 *)(*piVar1 + 0x11c));
  (**(code **)(*piVar1 + 0x120))(piVar1,*(undefined4 *)(*piVar1 + 0x124));
  (**(code **)(*piVar1 + 0x110))(piVar1,*(undefined4 *)(*piVar1 + 0x114));
                    // WARNING: Bad instruction - Truncating control flow here
  halt_baddata();
}
```

Looks like `func_0xffb2876c()` something like `GetSingletonInstance()` and subsequent 4 calls is a virtual methods.